# Stringency vs humour in editing

Tags: discussion, humor

Sometimes I get to review edits to really funny questions which it usually is clear (to me) what is meant in the question but mis-spelled or phrased in funny ways. Is there some policy as how important it is to be strict in formulating questions or is humour in questions encouraged?

I could see both ways here. Some hard working users get demotivated by silliness and unseriousness but some probably also get demotivated by too strict or dry environments.

Comment: [An example in meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9179/cereal-downvotes)

Comment: One problem is what is "really funny"? I for one do not find the example given by @JohnMa funny at all. (I did read things from Will Jagy that I did find quite funny, but not this.)

Comment: quid makes a valid point; may I also add that if somebody gets demotivated by  seriousness in Mathematics they're  probably in the wrong subject.

Comment: I did not mean demotivated about the subject per se but demotivated from contributing to the site if they find the atmosphere too boring, unpleasant or strict.

Comment: Well the site "should" be an approximation to the subject, no?

Comment: A site for encouraging people to exchange ideas about a subject. If people are in practice (by accident or otherwise) discouraged from exchanging ideas then it does not accomplish that goal very well.

Comment: I agree with mathreadler. Online forums in math/science/tech are already notorious, for example, for being extremely unwelcoming to women. (And I know of no evidence that math.stackexchange is any different, and indeed know of specific women who will no longer post here.) When half the population finds a community unwelcoming, it's the community's fault, not the fault of that popoulation's "motivation".

Comment: @GregMartin, for what it's worth, I know many guys who find this site unwelcoming, too. Perhaps what's really going on is that this site is unwelcoming *in general,* and perhaps it is the case that when women find a site that is male-dominated and unwelcoming, they're likely to conclude that this is due to gender, whereas when men find a site that is male-dominated and unwelcoming, they're more likely to conclude that its just a crappy site and a crappy community.

Comment: (Continued.) Of course, its probably also the case that MSE harbors a few *actual* misogynists, which, if true, would make the experience even worse for women. I suppose the community has already discussed this problem.

Comment: Rephrasing your comment: if someone concludes that this site is unwelcoming in a gender-related way, then they must be a woman and their conclusion is wrong. Thank you for demonstrating my point.

Comment: Your point being that massive amount of learning is done to young girls that they are oppressed and should learn to view themselves as victims almost no matter what happens in life? Or what else would your point be?

Comment: @goblin How is "male-dominated" (sufficiently immediately) observable in the first place? A username like GregMartin may *suggest* a real-life male behind it, likewise mathreader has a profile image that may *suggest* a female user - though the image is apparently not his/hers.

Comment: @GregMartin, sorry, I only just saw your replies now. But I'm not sure I follow; what point of yours did I demonstrate? All I was really trying to say is that its entirely possible that people who belong to groups who are often treated unfairly will sometimes perceive poor treatment as being caused by their membership in said groups, and often they will be right, but sometimes they will be partly wrong. And this is probably happens doubly as frequently in cyber communities, where body language and other non-verbal cues aren't available. By the way, I agree completely with the comment that...

Comment: ..."when half the population finds a community unwelcoming, it's the community's fault." However, I think that much much more than half the population finds the website unwelcoming, and I think this deserves attention. We should be careful not to let issues of race or gender (which are, of course, definitely very important) completely distract us from other issues, like our general treatment of newcomers. That's really all I was trying to say.

Comment: @mathreadler, my point wasn't very clear, but I was really just trying to suggest that while the perception that this site is unwelcoming to women is no doubt an accurate perception, nonetheless this perception is also no-doubt partly based on the fact that this site is unwelcoming to people in *general.* I think that as a general rule, it's not always clear why any given space is unwelcoming to any given person, so inevitably, we jump to conclusions about why it is unwelcoming - this is human nature - and sometimes these conclusions are correct, but sometimes they're at least partly wrong.

Comment: @mathreadler: Please don't be naive. Oppression is not imaginary. Disparaging victims of oppression for knowing that oppression happens to them (as you did above) is part of the problem. If you don't want women to be victims of sexism, then fight against sexism.

Comment: @goblin: You have described a proposed bias, on the part of women, to (sometimes) see sexism where it might not exist. Have you contemplated another bias, on the part of men, to (by default) fail to perceive sexism where it might in fact exist? Which bias do you think is more prevalent in general? in STEM forums?

Comment: @GregMartin, well *everyone* is deeply biased, of course, but I don't think I'm describing a bias. All I'm saying is that, given limited information, people tend to try to "fill in the gaps" in the most reasonable and likely way, and this sometimes works, and it sometimes doesn't. So I'm emphatically not saying "women are using an irrational or unreasonable strategy for drawing conclusions here." I'm not an arsehole. I'm actually saying something much more moderate: I'm saying that some women may be using a perfectly rational, completely reasonable strategy for drawing conclusions here, but...

Comment: ... that in this particular case, that strategy may be resulting in inferences that exaggerate the role of sexism in the general unwelcomingness of this particular site. I then go on to concede that there are probably some people on this site that specifically have it in for women, and that, if so, this would make their experience here *even worse.* Note also that my every comment on this topic is punctuated by "perhaps, maybe, likely, some," which strongly indicates that I'm not completely dismissing your original comment, because after all, I more or less agree with it.

Comment: I should also add that I don't know about other "tech" forums. I only really know about stackexchange and mathoverflow. It's possible, for example, that certain other tech forums actually have a very warm and welcoming culture, unless you're (perceived to be) a woman, in which case suddenly the forum becomes unwelcoming and awful. I don't think this is really a good description of math.stackexchange, however. In my two years on these sites, I've seen very little overt sexism, barring one particularly egregious example. I have, however, seen a lot of poor treatment of newcomers in general.

Comment: @GregMartin, I should add that I completely agree with your comment to mathreadler. The statement "disparaging victims of oppression for knowing that oppression happens to them is part of the problem" is obviously true.

Comment: My point was to claim that teaching the victims to be the ones to feel bad about stuff is part of the oppression. Successful learning in the victims that they actually are victims can make the oppression more efficient as it creates a feeling of helplessness. The problem runs deeper than "fighting against sexism". It's about what kids learn when they are small. How do we react when a little girl does something and when a little boy does the same?

Comment: @mathreadler, well, I think that's going off on a bit of a tangent, but anyway, learning "people will sometimes try to make you a victim because of [...]" is different from learning "you are a victim because of [...]." Obviously, these will tend to have opposite effects on the would-be victim's attitude and behavior; furthermore, it seems extremely unlikely that someone who opposes gender discrimination will attempt to teach the latter to young people. In any event, I feel that this is getting further and further from the topic Greg Martin and I are trying to discuss.

Comment: I guess the tangent started off with the gender discussions altogether. It's starting to add up to some comments by now. Maybe we should make a chat about it instead.